# Given $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle C = 60^\circ$, show $a^2+b^2-ab=c^2$ without trigonometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I have the following problem:

> In $\triangle ABC$, the angle at vertex $C$ is $60^{\circ}$. Prove that $a^2+b^2-ab=c^2$.

Of course, it is easy if you use cosine rule. I believe there exists a beautiful proof as well without using trigonometry. Anyone?

Comment: If $\angle A=60^\circ$, then it should be $a^2=b^2+c^2-bc$.

Comment: where is the angle $60^{\circ}$ situated?

Comment: Obviously go for pythagorus theorem then.

Comment: Suggest adjusting as Zhuoran mentions, or starting with vertex $C$ being the one assumed to be 60 degrees.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe if that is the case then we get $$a^2 + b^2 - ab = 2b^2 + c^2 - bc - ab = c^2$$ and thus, $$ab + bc = 2b^2\Leftrightarrow a + c = 2b$$

Answer (score 3):

Without using trigonometry, we can use Stewart's theorem.

We build an equilateral triangle as shown in the attached figure so we have

$$b^2(a-b)+c^2b=ab(a-b)+b^2a$$ which is equivalent to the given $$a^2+b^2-ab=c^2$$

[image]

Comment: @Blue: Dear Friend: I received by e. m. (together with others) your last comment (not appeared here) in which you say correctly Heron instead of Theron (what has happened is that there is a professor in Montpellier named Theron and I had a lapsus). Your message in the e. m. is not completed (just the beginning appears) and I was frustrated by the impossibility of read all of it. Regards.

Comment: Isn't all this superficial or to be bolder, fake? You sponsor this theorem but when it comes to its proof, we use same old trigonometry OR Pythagoras theorem as I show in answer. Regards.

Comment: @King Tut: I do not see in any way that Blue's idea of associating trigonometry with geometry as forming a unified part of a whole is false. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito: I deleted my previous comments because my contention that Stewart's Theorem required the Law of Cosines (so that your answer didn't satisfy OP's desire for an answer avoiding that Law) was embarrassingly incorrect: Stewart can *obviously* be proven via Pythagoras alone.

Comment: @Blue: Intellectual honesty is a great quality of the true mathematician. Regards dear friend.

Answer (score 2):

Drop perpendicular from $C$ onto $AB$ and call foot of perpendicular as $D$. Then using pythagoras theorem, 
$$AD^2 + DC^2 = b^2 \tag{1}$$ 
$$DC^2 + DB^2 = a^2\tag{2}$$ 
and from  side $c$ 
$$AD + DB = c \tag{3}$$

[image]

Finally we need a relation that comes from the angle $A$ being $60^\circ$. Consider the triangle $ADC.$ Make a midpoint $E$ on $AC$ and join $ED$. Thus from what **Arnaldo** showed, we can show 
$$AD = \frac{b}{2}\tag{4}$$

So you have to just eliminate between these equations.

Comment: It feels like with some work, either using that 3 times 60 is a flat angle, or using Pythagoras repeatedly we should be able to avoid trigonometry.

Comment: The OP asks not use trigonometrics.

Comment: Before you bash me up with a punches on the unlike button, I already know he said to avoid trigonometry. I said in my answer that I couldn't avoid it using once. Thats all.

Comment: I don't know why you think that I will give you a downvote. I'm just making an observation.

Comment: Arnaldo I am sorry for inconvenience, and I have edited my answer. Your observation is interesting! I have utilised it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\leq b$ and $BD$ be an altitude of the triangle.

Thus, since $$\measuredangle A\leq\frac{180^{\circ}-60^{\circ}}{2}=60^{\circ},$$
we see that $D$ is placed between $A$ and $C$.

Hence, $DC=\frac{a}{2}$, $AD=b-\frac{a}{2}$, $BD=\frac{\sqrt3a}{2}$ and by Pythagoras we obtain: 
$$c^2=\left(b-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt3a}{2}\right)^2=a^2-ab+b^2.$$

Comment: You post same answer as me after me yet received more likes. Regards.

Comment: Yes something in your words. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proof using [Ptolemy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem):

[image]

$$\begin{align}
|\overline{AB}| |\overline{A^\prime B^\prime}| &= |\overline{AA^\prime}||\overline{BB^\prime}|+|\overline{AB^\prime}||\overline{A^\prime B}| \tag{1} \\[4pt]
c^2 &= a b + ( a - b )^2 \tag{2} \\[4pt]
&= a^2 + b^2 - a b \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

---

Incidentally, the Wikipedia entry mentions that one can use Ptolemy to prove the Law of Cosines generally. However, the description there isn't as clear as it might be. All one needs to do is observe that, in general, 
$$|\overline{AA^\prime}| = 2b\sin\frac{C}{2} \qquad |\overline{BB^\prime}| = 2a\sin\frac{C}{2} \tag{4}$$
so that the counterpart of $(2)$ is
$$c^2 = 4ab\sin^2\frac{C}{2} + ( a - b )^2 \tag{5}$$
and we have
$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b \left( 1 - 2\sin^2\frac{C}{2} \right) = a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b \cos C \tag{6}$$

Comment: This is a nice answer, provides alternate viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

[image]

Using the picture you get $q=p$.

Now think about the next picture:

[image]

Comment: The other angles should be arbitrary, the only constraint on them being that they sum up to $120°$.

Comment: @Allawonder, you are right but my triangle is not that one of the statement. You can use it to solve the more general one. This is just a hint, not a full solution. BTW, I don't understand the downvote. People first should think a little bit before press the button.

Comment: I see. So how does your hint help?

Comment: @Allawonder: take another look

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: we have an isosceles triangle with 60º as a base angle.

Comment: Removed downvote because now I see how your solution works, but you could have made it a bit more clear from the beginning - it is still not obvious.

Comment: @Arnaud Its not complete, but it gives a key point that I completely missed. I liked his answer to credit him

Comment: @KingTut, thanks for the mention in your answer. I gave to the OP a hint, not a full solution. I usually do that. I think that to leave some work to the OP can help him to solve the question by himself.

Comment: In the first diagram we obviously do NOT have $q=p$........... Typo?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: There is no typo! We do have $q=p$

Comment: Yes you certainly do!

Comment: This is one  answer which shows key reasoning and is conveniently ignored by this site's crowd.